# How to get pickervalue from action sheet in iOS?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uipickerview, uiactionsheet

In my app, when button is pressed, I am launching `UIActionSheet` with `UIPickerView` and `UIToolBar` in it. Its working perfectly by using the following code. **I am trying to get the picker value and set that value to the called button, but I couldn't find the exact solution for it.**

```
- (IBAction)showPicker:(id)sender {

 actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil 
                                                         delegate:self
                                                cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                           destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];//as we want to display a subview we won't be using the default buttons but rather we're need to create a toolbar to display the buttons on 

[actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];

CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0);

pickerView = [[UIPickerView     alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
pickerView.dataSource = self;
pickerView.delegate = self;

[actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];
//[pickerView release];     

pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
pickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
[pickerToolbar sizeToFit];

NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];   

UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];  
[barItems addObject:flexSpace];  

UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonPressed:)];  
[barItems addObject:doneBtn];  

UIBarButtonItem *cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancelButtonPressed:)];  
[barItems addObject:cancelBtn];  


[pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];  

[actionSheet addSubview:pickerToolbar];  

[actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];  

[actionSheet showInView:self.view];  

[actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];
```

}

When Done button in Tool bar pressed it will call this method

```
-(void)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender{  
//Do something here here with the value selected using [pickerView date] to get that value   
[actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:1 animated:YES];   
[pickerView release];
[pickerToolbar release];
[actionSheet release];     
}
```

Here is my questions

How to get The picker value from action sheet?

How to set that value to the button?

Thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the pickerView datasource has only one component you can get the selected row using:

```
NSInteger row = [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. do i want to use it in `doneButtonPressed` method..and also how to get picker value from this phik.. thanks

Comment: yes do that in doneButtonPressed. The value is in your datasource, so use `[self pickerView:pickerView titleForRow:row forComponent:0]`.

Comment: Thanks for your support.. Sorry for delay in accepting the answer just now had a change to test my code.. Thanks +1

Answer (score 1):

Just create one ivar in your .h or .m and assign the `[pickerView date]` to the ivar and you are done with getting the value from ActionSheet.

Happy Coding :)

**EDIT**

in your `-(void)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender` method just put this line of code

```
selected = [pickerView date];
```

And `selected` is the `NSDate` type ivar declared in .h as below

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *selected;
```

And have to declare one property for datePicker also

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIDatePicker *pickerView;
```

And in .m synthesize it as below

```
@synthesize pickerView;
@synthesize selected;
```

Happy Coding :)

**Edit 1**

For custom pickerView

(I assume that all the delegate and datasources for pickerView is defined and declared)

to get selected value from custom picker have to use the below mentioned code

```
NSInteger row = [singlePicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
NSString *selected = [pickerData objectAtIndex:row];
```

`singlePicker` = pickerView and `pickerData` is `NSArray` which is used as datasource for pickerView

May this will help you to solve your problem.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry i am new to iOS and couldn't get you.. whats the [pickerView date] and if possible could you say how to set text for button

Comment: i am sorry i am not using any date here.. the pickerview values is from NSArray.. how you will get `selected = [pickerView date]` from my code.. thanks

Comment: oh k.. got it will update the answer for custom pickerView. That will solve your problem